# Apply z-index descending to li with jQuery

Tags: jquery, z-index

I need to count the li's and then add z-index in reverse order, to look like:

```
<li style="z-index:3;"></li>
<li style="z-index:2;"></li>
<li style="z-index:1;"></li>
```

I do not want 0 or negatives on any z-indexes, and it needs to be in reverse order. I would like to use jQuery since I won't know how many li's will be on this list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    var numIndex = $("ul.progress li").length + 1;
    $("ul.progress li").each(
      function(numIndex) {
        $(this).css("z-index", numIndex*-1);
    });
```

Please advise if you know what I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you know you can [pass a callback argument to `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value)?

```
var c = $('#list li').length;
$('#list li').css('z-index', function(i) {
    return c - i;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/XuSX8/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var numIndex = $("ul.progress li").length;

    $("ul.progress li").each(function(i){
        $(this).css("z-index", numIndex-i);
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/F39WC/

Answer (score 0):

You have to take out the `.each()` function param:

```
var numIndex = $("ul.progress li").length;
$("ul.progress li").each(function () {
   $(this).css("z-index", numIndex--);
});
```